# Implementation Prefix Mode

Tags: java, tcp

I'm developing a server-client application.
The server is done in Java (PC) and the client in Java. (Android)

I'm having trouble with the following implementation:

> Server grabs bitmap -> raw bytes -> TCP -> Client (Async Streams

Now the byte array is delivered in multiple packets of different lengths in the client. So to handle this properly, I should use the prefix method.

> To use prefix mode you need to send the length of the message in bytes
>   as four bytes and then the message

My code

```
public void sendScreenshot(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    os.write(buffer.length + 1);
    os.write((byte) 0);
    os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    os.flush();
}
```

In VB.net, this is achieved in the following code:

```
Private Sub dat(ByVal dat As String)
    Dim nstream As NetworkStream = sock.GetStream()
    Dim bit As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dat)
    Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(sock.GetStream())
    bw.Write(bit.Length + 1)
    bw.Write((byte)command)
    bw.Write(bit, 0, bit.length)

End Sub
```

Any help implementing it in Java is welcome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`DataOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html):

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(os);
out.writeInt(buffer.length + 1);
// This writes a single byte
out.write(0);
out.write(buffer);
out.flush();
```

The `.writeInt()` here comes from this part of the text you quoted:

> you need to send the length of the message in bytes as four bytes

which means an `int`. Note that this will write the int in network order. While this is unspecified in your extract, I suppose this is what is expected.

Similarly, on the receiving end, you can use a [`DataInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), read the length as an int and then the payload.

Comment: @XverhelstX Note that what you were doing with `write(buffer.length+1)` was calling `write(int)`, which writes a single byte. I don't know why you added +1.